# Add shadow to every section in grouped table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

As shown in image I want to add shadow to my table view sections. As like table view has 4 section then there would be 4 shadow view in table view.

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3    }

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch processIndex {
        return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return  44
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return UIView
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
}
```

[image]

Comment: Need to see some code for your `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`.

Comment: Can u update some code in your question? What u have tried? From that, we can give our best.

Comment: i had updated the code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried with custom `[String : UIView]` . This will work for minimum number of rows. If your cell's design is static, this will satisfy your design. If you want to access some property inside `UITableViewCell`, you have to go with subviews.

- Multiple section with only one row. Only one view (`lookView`) inside that respective row.
- We have to create n number of `UIView` programatically based on requirement.
- `UITapGesture` to `TableView` . `TableView` format is `Grouped`, `Separator` as `.none`.

Following code will give output like:

[image: screenShot]

```
//Global Variable:


@IBOutlet weak var tblVw: UITableView!

var rowItemsDict = [String : [String]]()
var rowHeight = [String : CGFloat]()
var eachRowSubViews = [String : UIView]()


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    rowItemsDict = ["0" : ["welcome", "hello", "wow", "Good", "Bad"], "1" : ["Asia", "Europe", "America"], "2" : ["Mcdonald", "Pizza", "Fries"]]

    for i in 0..<rowItemsDict.count
    {
        let numOfSubItemsArr : [String] = rowItemsDict[String(i)]!
        let eachRowHeight : CGFloat = getShadowViewHeight(defaultHeight: 44.0, numberOfItems: numOfSubItemsArr.count)

        var subArrView = UIView()

        for j in 0..<numOfSubItemsArr.count
        {
            let sublabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tblVw.frame.size.width - 42, height: 39))
            sublabel.text = numOfSubItemsArr[j]
            sublabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            sublabel.textAlignment = .right
            sublabel.textColor = UIColor.red
            let subView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: CGFloat((j * 40)), width: tblVw.frame.size.width, height: 39))
            subView.addSubview(sublabel)
            subView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            subView.tag = ((i+1) * 100) + j

            if j == (numOfSubItemsArr.count - 1)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                let LinesubView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 38, width: tblVw.frame.size.width - 8, height: 1))
                LinesubView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
                subView.addSubview(LinesubView)
            }

            subView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            subArrView.addSubview(subView)
            subArrView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }

        eachRowSubViews[String(i)] = subArrView
        rowHeight[String(i)] = eachRowHeight
    }

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapEachView))
    tblVw.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    tblVw.reloadData()
}


// TABLEVIEW DELEGATES
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {


    return rowItemsDict.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SampleTableViewCell

    print("\n\ncellFor")
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 240/255, green: 240/255, blue: 240/255, alpha: 0.0)
    cell.separatorVw.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 250/255, green: 250/255, blue: 250/255, alpha: 0.0)
    tableView.clipsToBounds = true
    let gettingVw : UIView = eachRowSubViews[String(indexPath.section)]!
    cell.lookVw.addSubview(gettingVw)
    cell.lookVw.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    cell.separatorVw.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = cell as! SampleTableViewCell

    cell.lookVw.dropOnlyOneShadowLeft(getSize: CGSize.zero)
    cell.lookVw.backgroundColor = UIColor.white


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return (rowHeight[String(indexPath.section)]! )

}


//ROW HEIGHT CALCULATION
func getShadowViewHeight(defaultHeight: CGFloat, numberOfItems: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    let requiredHeight = CGFloat(Int(defaultHeight) * numberOfItems)

    return requiredHeight
}

//TAP GESTURE ACTION
@objc func tapEachView(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    let touchPoint = sender.location(in: tblVw)
    let index = tblVw.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint)

    if (index == nil)
    {
            print("long press on table view but not on a row");
    }
    else
    {
        let cell = tblVw.cellForRow(at: index!) as! SampleTableViewCell
        let pointInCell = cell.convert(touchPoint, from: tblVw)

        let innerSubVw = cell.lookVw.subviews
        print("pointInCellpointInCell)  ", pointInCell)
        for sVw in innerSubVw[0].subviews
        {
            let pointY = pointInCell.y - 5
            let comparePoint = sVw.frame.origin.y

            if pointY >= comparePoint && pointY <= comparePoint + 39
            {
                print("sVwsVwsVwsVwsVw    ", sVw.tag)

                //DO YOUR ACTION IN RESPECTIVE VIEW CLICK
                return
            }

        }

    }
}


extension UIView {
    func dropOnlyOneShadowLeft(getSize: CGSize) {
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
        self.layer.shadowOffset = getSize
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 3
    }
}
```

Comment: could you mail me demo please

Comment: Mail address? I wil mail

Comment: adiindia.sharma@gmail.com

Comment: can you please share demo ? GitHub , drive ?

Comment: I tried but didn't can you please share in Github or Drive link ?

Comment: give ur mail id ?

Comment: @McDonal_11 Hi... great soution.. I wanted exactly the same.. It's just that i want to show the heading as well.. Like in your case  "0","1" as header of the sections.Please tell me how you show 0 , 1, 2 as titles of the section.please.. and also what is `separatorVw ` ? how you take it.

Answer (score 13):

There is an easier way to show shadow for every section.

1. set the background color of your table view to `UIColor.clear`
2. set table view style as Grouped (or for iOS 13+ you can even select `Inset Grouped` style which will also add corners to each section)
3. add shadow to the whole table view. This will drop shadow to every section

To add shadow to the table view:

```
tableView.layer.masksToBounds = false
tableView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.4).cgColor // any value you want
tableView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1 // any value you want
tableView.layer.shadowRadius = 100 // any value you want
tableView.layer.shadowOffset = .init(width: 0, height: 10) // any value you want
```

[image: Result]

Comment: This was brilliant, no need to do cell level manipulations.

Comment: This is a great solution. Is there any way to not add the shadow to a section or header? My table view has a header and I don't want to apply the shadow to it.

Comment: `tableView.layer.masksToBounds = false` - man it breaks your `tableView`

Comment: @Gargo it depends on your case. If the table is covering full screen there shouldn't be any issues.

Answer (score 3):

This will set the shadow for only the sections and not the header/footer:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
tableView.subviews.forEach { view in
    view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
    view.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 3
}
```

Comment: I know I come late to the party, but in my opinion this should be the the accepted solution