# Tableview cell on iOS 9 and above like iOS 6

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

mates

I am trying to duplicate the exact look of iOS 6 tableview static cell and section of static cells on iOS 9 and above with Swift 4.

I want to achieve this look:

[image]

This code rounds the cell edges:

```
@IBOutlet weak var cell: UITableViewCell!
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Questions:

1. How to round the edges of a section?
2. How to indent cell and section borders inwards?

Comment: None of the solutions in the topic are written in Swift 4. None works on iOS10 and above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433282/add-shadow-to-every-section-in-grouped-table-view/48442880#48442880

Comment: You may get some idea, how to achieve that.